# Windbg: Creating log of function entry and exit

Tags: windbg

I wish to create log of function entry and exit for my code. I am using the following command in WinDbg-
Function name and the return value

```
bm <module_name>!* "kcL1;.echotime;gu;r eax;.echotime;gc;"
```

Now I wish to do this for all the modules of the function but I don't want to write the code again for each module. Is there some way to specify bm to read module names from a file which I create using "lm" and set breakpoint for each module or something even more simple.

Also, how can I specify bm to not print the output on the screen? I am using a log file.

Sometimes I don't see the time for call exit. What can be the reason for this? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`!for_each_module`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563136%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You will not see call exit time if another breakpoint is hit (in another thread, or if the funciton calls other functions that have breakpoints)